# JavaScript sync two arrays (of objects) / find delta

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I have two arrays, old and new, which hold objects at each position. How would I sync or find the delta (i.e. what is new, updated and deleted from the new array compared to the old array)

```
var o = [
    {id:1, title:"title 1", type:"foo"},
    {id:2, title:"title 2", type:"foo"},
    {id:3, title:"title 3", type:"foo"}
];

var n = [
    {id:1, title:"title 1", type:"foo"},
    {id:2, title:"title updated", type:"foo"},
    {id:4, title:"title 4", type:"foo"}
];
```

With the above data, using id as the key, we'd find that item with id=2 has an updated title, item with id=3 is deleted, and item with id=4 is new.

Is there an existing library out there that has useful functions, or is it a case of loop and inner loop, compare each row..e.g.

```
for(var i=0, l=o.length; i<l; i++)
{   
    for(var x=0, ln=n.length; x<ln; x++)
    {
        //compare when o[i].id == n[x].id    
    }  
}
```

Do this kind of comparison three times, to find new, updated and deleted?

Comment: You could speed things up a little, if the ids are unique and you use an object with the id as keys.

Comment: You should explain what is the output? An object with three properties? `{added: 4], changed: [2], deleted: [3]}`

Comment: Output would probably be best in three arrays. The deleted would only need IDs, added and changed would need the full "row" / object

Comment: @Sirko the input will always be arrays of objects. I could of course convert them to objects with keys before the comparison starts

Comment: @Fergal: Since they are arrays, is their order important? Or do they represent sets?

Comment: @Bergi: if there is something unique to use as an identifier, then order is not important. I may also want to perform a sync where there is no identifier. In that case order would be important because there is nothing else to find what objects should be compared.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no magic to do what you need. You need to iterate through both objects looking for changes. A good suggestion is to turn your structure into maps for faster searches.

```
/**
 * Creates a map out of an array be choosing what property to key by
 * @param {object[]} array Array that will be converted into a map
 * @param {string} prop Name of property to key by
 * @return {object} The mapped array. Example:
 *     mapFromArray([{a:1,b:2}, {a:3,b:4}], 'a')
 *     returns {1: {a:1,b:2}, 3: {a:3,b:4}}
 */
function mapFromArray(array, prop) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        map[ array[i][prop] ] = array[i];
    }
    return map;
}

function isEqual(a, b) {
    return a.title === b.title && a.type === b.type;
}

/**
 * @param {object[]} o old array of objects
 * @param {object[]} n new array of objects
 * @param {object} An object with changes
 */
function getDelta(o, n, comparator)  {
    var delta = {
        added: [],
        deleted: [],
        changed: []
    };
    var mapO = mapFromArray(o, 'id');
    var mapN = mapFromArray(n, 'id');    
    for (var id in mapO) {
        if (!mapN.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            delta.deleted.push(mapO[id]);
        } else if (!comparator(mapN[id], mapO[id])){
            delta.changed.push(mapN[id]);
        }
    }

    for (var id in mapN) {
        if (!mapO.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            delta.added.push( mapN[id] )
        }
    }
    return delta;
}

// Call it like
var delta = getDelta(o,n, isEqual);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/wjdZ6/1/ for an example

Comment: Thanks, saves me having to think too hard ;)

Comment: @Fergal That's not a good thing, the better thing for you to would be  to try it on your own, and then ask questions if you couldn't get it to work. If you can get it to work but want suggestions, then you can ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, I was kind of joking. I did try and got it working mostly (a few more lines required is all) while keeping an eye on this page. But the way you converted the arrays to objects really reduced the lines of code (using hasOwnProperty)

Comment: @JuanMendes I have a similar issue. I have array with more values like this: `{id:3, title:"title 3", mobileNumber: "123456789", email: "xyz@gmail.com" type:"foo"}` . You are checking using `a.title == b.title` but how do I check when I have more values?

Comment: @satyadev just implement your isEqual with all the required checks

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm confused how do I return a Boolean value when `a.title==b.title` is true and `a.email==b.email` is false ?

Comment: `return a.title==b.title && a.email==b.email`

Answer (score 3):

This is typescript version of `@Juan Mendes` answer

```
  mapFromArray(array: Array<any>, prop: string): { [index: number]: any } {
    const map = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      map[array[i][prop]] = array[i];
    }
    return map;
  }

  isEqual(a, b): boolean {
    return a.title === b.title && a.type === b.type;
  }

  getDelta(o: Array<any>, n: Array<any>, comparator: (a, b) => boolean): { added: Array<any>, deleted: Array<any>, changed: Array<any> } {
    const delta = {
      added: [],
      deleted: [],
      changed: []
    };
    const mapO = this.mapFromArray(o, 'id');
    const mapN = this.mapFromArray(n, 'id');
    for (const id in mapO) {
      if (!mapN.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        delta.deleted.push(mapO[id]);
      } else if (!comparator(mapN[id], mapO[id])) {
        delta.changed.push(mapN[id]);
      }
    }

    for (const id in mapN) {
      if (!mapO.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        delta.added.push(mapN[id]);
      }
    }
    return delta;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as `@Juan Mendes` but for built-in Maps and a bit more efficient (on finding added values)

```
function mapDelta(oldMap, newMap, compare) {

    var delta = {
        added: [],
        deleted: [],
        changed: []
    };

    var newKeys = new Set(newMap.keys());

    oldMap.forEach(function (oldValue, oldKey) {
        newKeys.delete(oldKey);
        var newValue = newMap.get(oldKey);
        if (newValue == undefined) {
            delta.deleted.push({ key: oldKey, value: oldValue });
            return;
        }
        else if (!compare(oldValue, newValue)) {
            delta.changed.push({ key: oldKey, oldValue: oldValue, newValue: newValue });
        }
    });

    newKeys.forEach(function (newKey) {
        delta.added.push({ key: newKey, value: newMap.get(newKey) });
    });

    return delta;
}
```

and using `typescript`

```
function mapDelta<K, T>(oldMap: Map<K, T>, newMap: Map<K, T>, compare: (a: T, b: T) => boolean) {

  const delta = {
    added: [] as { key: K, value: T }[],
    deleted: [] as { key: K, value: T }[],
    changed: [] as { key: K, oldValue: T, newValue: T }[]
  };

  const newKeys = new Set(newMap.keys());

  oldMap.forEach((oldValue, oldKey) => {
    newKeys.delete(oldKey);
    const newValue = newMap.get(oldKey);
    if (newValue == undefined) {
      delta.deleted.push({ key: oldKey, value: oldValue });
      return;
    } else if (!compare(oldValue, newValue)) {
      delta.changed.push({ key: oldKey, oldValue: oldValue, newValue: newValue });
    }
  })

  newKeys.forEach((newKey) => {
    delta.added.push({ key: newKey, value: newMap.get(newKey) });
  })

  return delta;
}
```