# Compare two two arrays to add or remove records from database

Tags: php, arrays, database, comparison, pseudocode

Maybe today's been a long week, but I'm starting to run in circles with trying to figure out the logic on how to solve this.

To use the classic Orders and Items example, we have a webform that tabulates the data of an EXISTING Order e.g. saved in the db.

Now this form needs the ability to add/"mark as removed" ItemIDs from an order after the order has been 'saved'.  When the form is submitted, I have two arrays:

`$ogList` = The original ItemIDs for the OrderID in question. (ex. `[123, 456, 789]`)

`$_POST['items']` = The modifications of ItemIDs, if any (ex. `[123, 789, 1240, 944]`)

The intent is to compare the two arrays and:

1) Add new ItemIDs (never have been related to this OrderID before)

2) Mark the date 'removed' those ItemIDs that weren't $_POSTed.

The simple approach of just removing the existing ItemIDs from the Order, and adding the $_POSTed list won't work for business reasons.

PHP's array_diff() doesn't really tell me which ones are "new".

So what's the best way to do this?  It appears that I'm looking at a nested foreach() loop ala:

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $posted){
   foreach($ogList as $ogItem){
      if($posted == $ogItem){
         Open to ideas here.
     }
   }
 }
```

...with maybe conditional `break(1)` in there? Maybe there's a better way?

Another way to perhaps explain is to show the db records. The original in this example would be:

```
+--------+-------------+
| itemID | dateRemoved |
+--------+-------------+
|    123 |           0 |
|    456 |           0 |
|    789 |           0 |
```

After the POST, the ItemIDs in this OrderID would look something like:

```
+--------+-------------+
| itemID | dateRemoved |
+--------+-------------+
|    123 |           0 |
|    456 |  1368029148 |
|    789 |           0 |
|   1240 |           0 |
|    944 |           0 |
```

Does this make sense? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: I found [JavaScript sync two arrays (of objects) / find delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966207/javascript-sync-two-arrays-of-objects-find-delta), but I'm not nearly proficient enough to translate Javascript and maps. Though it gets me almost there.

Comment: `array_diff($_POST['items'], $ogList)` will tell you everything in `$_POST['items']` that isn't in `$ogList` (new items, I think, if I understand your example). `array_diff($ogList, $_POST['items'])` will tell you everything in `$ogList` that isn't in `$_POST['items')` (deleted items, if I understand your example). Am I missing something in your explanation?

Comment: HmmmmMmm. I recognized array_diff() as a potential, but I hadn't thought about using comparing the arrays "both" ways. That might be a potential solutions. Lemme tinker with that...... it seems that this might just work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you have items in databse and you receive new dokument with changed set of items, you obviously must update database. One of the easyest way is to delete all previous items and insert new list. But, in case that items is related to other data, you can't do that. So you must apply this technique of comparing two lists. You have items in database, you have items from client after dokument change and with bellow commands you can separate what is for insert in database, what you just need to update and what to delete from database. Below is a simplified example.

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];   //elements in database
$b = [2,3,4,6];     //elements after document save

$del = array_diff($a, $b);
//for delete 1, 5

$ins = array_diff($b, $a);
//for insert 6

$upd = array_intersect($a, $b);
//for update 2, 3, 4
```

As you can see, this simply compare elements, but if you want to insert real data, you must switch to associative arrays and compare keys. You need to array look something like this:

```
{
    "15":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"444","is_active":"1"},
    "16":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"555","is_active":"1"},
    "17":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"666","is_active":"1"},
    "18":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"777","is_active":"1"}
}
```

Here, you have ID extracted from data and placed in array key position. 
On server-side, that arrays can be eays get with PDO:

```
$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Beware that this will strip the first column from the resultset. So if you want to ID be on both places, use: "SELECT id AS arrkey, id, ... FROM ...".

On server side, when you make array, you don't need all data, just fetch id-s. That all need for compare, because key only matters:

```
[16=>16, 17=>17, 18=>18, 19=>19, 20=>20];
```

On client side, with JavaScript, you have to make same structured array of objects so can be compared on server. When you have new items on client, simply use Math.random() to genareate random key, because that doesn't matter.

```
let cards = {};
cards[Math.random()] = {
    employee_id: something,
    barcode: something,
    is_active: something
}
```

After that, from client you will get array like this:

```
{
    "16":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"555","is_active":"1"},
    "17":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"666","is_active":"1"},
    "18":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"777","is_active":"1"},
    "0.234456523454":{"employee_id":"1","barcode":"888","is_active":"1"}
}
```

item with Id 15 is deleted, 16, 17, 18 are changed (or not, you will update them anyway), and new item added. On server you can apply 3 way comparison with: **array_diff_key** and **array_intersect_key**.

So, for end, how this server side code looks in my case. First loop is on array keys and secound is to dynamically make UPDATE/INSERT statement.

```
//card differences
$sql = 'SELECT card_id AS arrkey, card_id FROM card WHERE (employee_id = ?)';
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);        
$sth->execute([$employee_id]);
$array_database = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);            
$array_client = json_decode($_POST['...'], true);

//cards update            
foreach (array_intersect_key($array_database, $array_client) as $id => $data) {
    $query = 'UPDATE card SET';
    $updates = array_filter($array_client[$id], function ($value) {return null !== $value;}); //clear nulls
    $values = [];
    foreach ($updates as $name => $value) {
        $query .= ' '.$name.' = :'.$name.','; 
        $values[':'.$name] = $value; 
    }
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1); // remove last comma

    $sth = $this->db->prepare($query . ' WHERE (card_id = ' . $id . ');');
    $sth->execute($values);
}

//cards insert
foreach (array_diff_key($array_client, $array_database) as $id => $card) {
    $prep = array();
    foreach($card as $k => $v ) {
        $prep[':'.$k] = $v;
    }
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO card ( " . implode(', ',array_keys($card)) . ") VALUES (" . implode(', ',array_keys($prep)) . ")");
    $sth->execute($prep); 
}

//cards delete
foreach (array_diff_key($array_database, $array_client) as $id => $data) {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM card WHERE card_id = ?');        
    $sth->execute([$id]);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.