# Javascript, how to transform this Array to Dictionary?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there an elegant way (map ?) to transform my object from this

```
[
  {id: 1, from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"},
  {id: 2, from: "1/3/2021", to: "1/4/2022"},
  {id: 1, from: "1/5/2021", to: "1/6/2022"},
  {id: 2, from: "1/6/2021", to: "1/7/2022"}
]
```

to:

```
{
  1: [{from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"}, {from: "1/5/2021", to: "1/6/2022"}],
  2: [{from: "1/3/2021", to: "1/4/2022"}, {from: "1/6/2021", to: "1/7/2022"}]
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
const res = [
  {id: 1, from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"},
  {id: 2, from: "1/3/2021", to: "1/4/2022"},
  {id: 1, from: "1/5/2021", to: "1/6/2022"},
  {id: 2, from: "1/6/2021", to: "1/7/2022"}
]

let dict = {};
for(var i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
   dict[res[i].id] = dict[res[i].id] || [];
   dict[res[i].id].push({from:res[i].from, to:res[i].to});
}
console.log(dict);
```

Comment: Try `mapFromArray` defined in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966749/227299 You should always post what you have tried so we can know where you're having difficulties. It's just creating a map from an array using one of its properties as the keys

Comment: Object properties must have a key. So your first example is not a valid object. Are those objects or arrays?

Comment: @JuanMendes I mean this `{  {id: 1, from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"} }` is not a valid object.

Comment: Sorry I was still editing my question you already answered. I've added my code. Can we do better with map or other js trick ?

Comment: @Eldar What happened when you ran your code? As Eldar mentioned, your first object is invalid syntax. Be sure to mention error messages and actual behavior https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would use `reduce` for that purpose

Comment: My mistake, the first one is correct but is an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `groupBy()` function to group by any property, in this case id. We'd use `Array.reduce()` to convert to the desired object.

Update: I've removed the `property` itself, in this case `id` from the resulting array groups.

```js
let input = [ {id: 1, from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"}, {id: 2, from: "1/3/2021", to: "1/4/2022"}, {id: 1, from: "1/5/2021", to: "1/6/2022"}, {id: 2, from: "1/6/2021", to: "1/7/2022"} ];

function groupBy(arr, property) {
    return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const { [property]: _, ...obj} = cur;
        acc[cur[property]] = [...(acc[cur[property]] || []), obj];
        return acc;
    }, {})
}

console.log(groupBy(input, 'id'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use [lodash groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) for this purpose, with a minimum of code:

```js
let input = [ {id: 1, from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"}, {id: 2, from: "1/3/2021", to: "1/4/2022"}, {id: 1, from: "1/5/2021", to: "1/6/2022"}, {id: 2, from: "1/6/2021", to: "1/7/2022"} ];

console.log('groupBy (lodash):', _.groupBy(input, 'id'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And, finally you can `reduce` using a `Map` object as well:

```js
let input = [ {id: 1, from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"}, {id: 2, from: "1/3/2021", to: "1/4/2022"}, {id: 1, from: "1/5/2021", to: "1/6/2022"}, {id: 2, from: "1/6/2021", to: "1/7/2022"} ];

function groupBy(arr, property) {
    return Object.fromEntries(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
        return acc.set(cur[property], [...(acc.get(cur[property]) || []), cur]);
    }, new Map()))
}

console.log(groupBy(input, 'id'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I understand well your code, this is generic whatever the key/values I have in each object? Your function isolates the specified key name, takes the associate values that become the new key name and all other key/values of the same object are arranged in an array and this array becomes the associated value!

Comment: Yes, you can group by whichever property you wish. Each property value will become a key in the resulting object, with each object sharing this key in an array.

Comment: Just tested your code in my project. The only minor issue is that the key is also in the array.

Comment: I'll update the answer to fix this!

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can solve your problem.

```js
const res = [
  {id: 1, from: "1/1/2021", to: "1/2/2022"},
  {id: 2, from: "1/3/2021", to: "1/4/2022"},
  {id: 1, from: "1/5/2021", to: "1/6/2022"},
  {id: 2, from: "1/6/2021", to: "1/7/2022"}
];

var result = res.reduce(function(acc, {id, from, to}) {
  (acc[id] = acc[id] || []).push({from, to});
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```